# Why is LUVOIR actively heated?

Tags: space-telescope

From the Wikipedia page about LUVOIR design:

> To enable the extreme wavefront stability needed for coronagraphic observations of Earth-like exoplanets, the LUVOIR design incorporates three principles. [...] . Third, the telescope is actively heated to a precise 270 K (26 °F) to control thermal disturbances.

I always thought the chiller a telescope mirror, the better. Why is LUVOIR heated then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason appears to be to prevent any icing up and contamination of the mirrors and other optical coponents with water and other "non-volatile residues", which would be extremely detrimental to the UV performance.

Emissivity at 270K is not too much of an issue since the instrument only works out to 2 microns.

The issue is briefly discussed in section 8.1.10 of the [LUVOIR final report](https://asd.gsfc.nasa.gov/luvoir/reports/LUVOIR_FinalReport_2019-08-26.pdf).